# After the ajax call keyup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After I load content using a ajax call my keyup function doesn't work, it works fine before the ajax call. I am using the following code, any help is much appreciated.

```
$(document).on('keyup','#Name',function( e ) { 
var key = e.which;
if(key == 13){
    add();
    }
});
```

Comment: this part of code should work fine after ajax.. be sure the element with id  #Name is already exists in the content

Comment: I know, I can't figure it out and element with id #Name is on page ajax being called from

Comment: do you have more than one element with that id?

Comment: There was a id in the new content that was loading same to #name, its working now!